# Combine JPA Query annotation with Oracle sample method

Tags: java, sql, jpa, spring-data-jpa

i am trying to pass a parameter into a JPA query
Example code

```
 @Query(value =
              "select *\n"
            + "from adress sample(:percentile)\n"
            + "where adress.number in (:adressNumbers)\n"
            + "fetch first (:rows) rows only,"
            + "nativeQuery = true
           List<X> sampleExample(Integer rows, List<Integer> adressNumbers, Double percentile)
```

But i get an error because of the sample(:percentile).
If i just hardcode a number in there it works but not with a param.
Is there a way to escape the brackets or something similar?
Thx

Comment: This _might_ work if you make your query native.  Otherwise, it is not valid JPQL and will not work.

Comment: I thought so. it is native but it wil error out at the sample method if provided with a parameter. so i guess there is no way around this.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: SQL command not properly ended

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is on the following part

```
from adress sample(:percentile)
```

Unfortunately it does not belong to the `where` part of the query and so the parameter passed `:percentile` can't be bound to the query.

There is not any quick fix around this. You won't be able to use a method parameter that will be able to be bound in the query in the part that you want it to be, because parameters can only be bound in the `where` part of the query.

Comment: I thought it was something like that but i guess we just have to make a few queries to use, each with a hardcoded sample. Thx for the explanation